# customErrors mode="Off" is not working

Tags: model-view-controller

I'm trying to upload my webapp to the provider. I can see only the default "Runtime error" message, telling me to turn off customErrors to view more about the error. I changed config file and still nothing. I made changes:

```
 <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
```

and nothig. When I upload other webapp to the same place everything is working fine. What other reason could couse the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server might have a configuration  that overrides your application settings and disables trace output, custom errors, and debug capabilities.

Find your machine.config file, which is located here by default:

..\Microsoft.NET\Framework\framework_version\CONFIG or

..\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\framework_version\CONFIG

In the machine.config file, there is a tag: .  When this is set, the ability to view detailed error information is taken away.  Note that this setting will override the web.config setting .  Set it to false by using 
`<deployment retail="false" />`and try  again.